# How to write nested subscribe in cleaner way?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am new with RxJS and I want to learn how to write code using it in clean way. I have nested subscription and I' ve tried to rewrite this, but with no result.

```
firstMethod() {
  this.testMethod(name)
  console.log(this.currentPerson)
}

testMethod() {
  this.myService.search(name).subscribe(response => {
    if(result) {
      this.currentPerson = result
    } else {
        this.myService.create(name).subscribe(result => {
          const person = {id: result.id, name: name}
          this.currentPerson = person
        })
      }
   })
}
```

Unfortunatelly despite the code is messy, there is something wrong with some piece after 'else' because console.log shows undefined.
Any tips how to fix it?

Comment: check [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To effectively handle nested subscribes, you should use one of the "[Higher Order Mapping Operator](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)", which do a few nice things for you:

1. maps the incoming value to another observable
2. subscribes to it, so its values are emitted into the stream
3. manages unsubscribing from these "inner subscriptions" automatically

In this case, `switchMap` is a good choice because it will only allow a single inner subscription at a time, so whenever `myService.search(name)` is called a new inner subscription for `myService.create(name)` is created, and the previous one is automatically unsubscribed.

@Rafi Henig's answer shows a good example of what this could look like.

- Notice the use of `.pipe()`.  You can define transformations to your observable output using pipeable operators without actually subscribing.

I would suggest you don't subscribe in your `testMethod()`, but rather return an observable.  Also, let's give "testMethod()" a more meaningful name for further discussion: "getPerson()".

```
getPerson(name: string): Observable<Person> {
  return this.myService.search(name).pipe(
    switchMap(result => {
      return iif(
        () => result,
        of(result),
        this.myService.create(name).pipe(
          map(({ id }) => ({ id, name }))
        )
      )
    }),
    tap(person => this.currentPerson = person)
  );
}
```

> console.log shows undefined. Any tips how to fix it?

```
1  firstMethod() {
2    this.getPerson(name)
3    console.log(this.currentPerson)
4  }
```

The reason for the `undefined` is because the code is asynchronous.  Line 2 is executed, then line 3 immediately after, but the async work hasn't been finished yet, so `this.currentPerson` hasn't been set yet.

since our `getPerson()` method now returns an observable, we can subscribe and do your `console.log()` inside the subscribe:

```
1  firstMethod() {
2    this.getPerson(name).subscribe(
3       () => console.log(this.currentPerson)
4    )
5  }
```

To simplify, we don't even need `this.currentPerson` anymore, because the person is emitted through the stream!

```
1  firstMethod() {
2    this.getPerson(name).subscribe(
3       person => console.log(person)
4    )
5  }
```

And since you want to...

> learn how to write code using it in clean way

I think think cleanest way would probably be to define your "person result" as an observable and ditch `this.currentPerson`.

```
person$ = this.getPerson(name);
```

So now you have `this.person$` which can be subscribed to and will always have the current value of person.  No need to "manually" update `this.currentPerson`.

Well... almost.  We need to consider what happens when the search term changes.

Let's assume the search term "name" is coming from a form control input.

When using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) the input value is an observable source, so we can define our `person$` from the search term:

```
searchTerm$ = this.searchInput.valueChanges();

person$ = this.searchTerm$.pipe(
  switchMap(searchTerm => this.getPerson(searchTerm))
);

getPerson(name: string): Observable<Person> {
  return this.myService.search(name).pipe(
    switchMap(result => {
      return iif(
        () => result,
        of(result),
        this.myService.create(name).pipe(
          map(({ id }) => ({ id, name }))
        )
      )
    })
  );
}
```

Notice we've defined two different observables, but we haven't subscribed yet! Now, we can leverage the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in our template to handle the subscription, keeping our component code nice and simple.

```
<p *ngIf="person$ | async as person">
  We found {{ person.name }} !
</p>
```

I know this has gotten a bit long winded, but I hope you see how its possible to  transform output using pipeable operators and how you can define one observable from another.

Answer (score 2):

Use [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) to return a new Observable based of the the value of `result` using [IIF operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) as demonstrated below:

```js
this.myService.search(name)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(result => {
      return iif(
        () => result,
        of(result),
        this.myService.create(name).pipe(map(({ id }) => ({ id, name })))
      )
    })
  )
  .subscribe(person => {

  })
```

Or optionally:

```js
this.myService.search(name)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(result => {
      if (result) return of(result);
      else this.myService.create(name).pipe(map(({ id }) => ({ id, name })));
    })
  )
  .subscribe(person => {

  })
```

Comment: Although the answer above is correct for the example shared, be mindful about what you are trying to do.
SwitchMap will automatically unsubscribe from the previous observable and subscribe to another one (given the control stream). In the example shared, it seems to be what you are trying to do (given you are updating a single property).
Nevertheless, there will be cases where you may want to keep every observable and a mergeMap, for example, would be better.

Take a look at @BizzyBob answer. It's pretty much complete