# Overriding previous observable

Tags: html, angular, rxjs

I have an events app which has an `all-events` component which lists all the created events. When the `all-events` component is loaded, the events are retrieved from my database.

This is the relevant code from the `all-events` Typescript file:

```
  eventParams: EventParams;
  getAllEventsObs: Observable<PaginatedResult<BeachCleanEvent[]>>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventParams = new EventParams();
    
  }

  getEvents() {
   this.getAllEventsObs = this.eventService.getAllEvents(this.eventParams);
  console.log("getting events");
  }

  pageChanged(event: any) {
    this.eventParams.pageNumber = event.page;
    this.eventService.setEventParams(this.eventParams);
    this.getEvents();
    
  }
```

Here is the html from the `all-events` component:

```
<div class="background-img">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="events-container" *ngIf="getAllEventsObs | async as getAllEventsObs">
      <div class="event-item" *ngFor="let event of getAllEventsObs.result">
        <app-event-card [existingEvent]="event"></app-event-card>
      </div>
      <pagination *ngIf="getAllEventsObs.pagination as eventPagination"
        [boundaryLinks]="true"
        [totalItems]="eventPagination.totalItems"
        [itemsPerPage]="eventPagination.itemsPerPage"
        [(ngModel)]="eventPagination.currentPage"
        (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)">
      </pagination>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `getAllEvents` method is just a simple http request. I won't show this code as I know it works correctly.

This is the `PaginatedResult` class:

```
export interface Pagination {
    currentPage: number;
    itemsPerPage: number;
    totalItems: number;
    totalPages: number;
}


export class PaginatedResult<T> {  
    result: T;  
    pagination: Pagination; 
}
```

This is the `EventParams` class:

```
export class EventParams {
    pageNumber = 1;
    pageSize = 4;
}
```

When the page initially loads, it loads correctly and displays the first four events:

[image]

The issue I am having is that when clicking on the next page, it gets stuck and won't load the next four events. No error is displayed on the console but the "getting events" `console.log` I created in the `getEvents` method above just keeps firing:

[image]

I suspect this is something to do with the way I am consuming the observable in the html code (using the async pipe). How would I go about resolving this? Is this where I should be using the `switchMap` RXJS operator? If so, how would I use it in this scenario?

Comment: maybe  this.getAllEventsObs.next(null) ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will attempt BizzyBobs answer first and then will try yours if it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track... and yes, you should use `switchMap` :-)

Instead of re-assigning your source observable inside `getEvents()`, you could simply define it to depend on your params, and just push new params when they change. `switchMap` will execute the service method each time the params change.

But if the `EventService` is keeping track of the params anyway, it's probably the simplest to have it expose the `events$` based on those params.

If you aren't already, define the params as a BehaviorSubject with default value and add a method for consumers to modify them.  Then expose a single `events$` observable that represents the events based on the specific params:

**service:**

```js
private params$ = new BehaviorSubject(new EventParams());

public setEventParams(params) {
   this.params$.next(params);
}

public events$ = this.params$.pipe(
    switchMap(params => this.getAllEvents(params))
);
```

**component:**

```js
  events$ = this.eventService.events$;

  pageChanged(params) {
    // build proper params object if necessary
    this.eventService.setEventParams(params);
  }
```

Your component code becomes a lot simpler since it doesn't need to be concerned with managing the observable and keeping track of params.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give this a go today and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Awesome this works! Still trying to get my head around `Switchmap`. So just so I understand what's happening here, whenever the `eventParams$` are set on the service, the `BehaviorSubject` is triggered with the new params. At this point, the `eventParams$` Observable is piped and the `Switchmap` switches the Observable from the `eventParams$` Observable to the Observable returned by the `getAllEvents` method. The `getAllEvents` Observable is then emitted and this is the Observable that is subscribed to in the component html. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I think you’ve got it! It also took me a while to wrap my head around switchMap. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63715772/1858357) might help solidify what’s going on and it also has a link about “higher order mapping operators” which might be helpful.